# Do merchants sell the same items to everyone in multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii

When playing with my friends, what do we see when browsing the merchant's wares?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Merchant loot is party-wide.** Everyone sees the same loot per merchant